# post_max_size will not change, stuck at 128M, other settings work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, upload

I am trying to increase post_max_size to 1024MB, I am using ini_get('post_max_size') and phpinfo() to check the setting and
post_max_size shows as 128M in both.

some phpinfo() on the server:

```
PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7
System  Linux Dalaran 3.13.0-49-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 20:11:33 UTC 2015 x86_64
Build Date  Mar 16 2015 20:43:56
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/apache2
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
Apache Version  Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
user_dir    no value
```

/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

```
669 ; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
670 ; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
671 ; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
672 ; http://php.net/post-max-size
673 post_max_size = 1024M
```

I have restarted apache after each change. I also ran a grep on all directories in /etc/php5 and found no other reference to Post_max_size

**Changing upload_max_filesize  and  memory_limit works fine.**

No user_dir is set, so it should not be loading any .user.ini files.

Nothing useful in apache error log.

If you have any ideas for what I can check next please tell me.

Comment: Have you verified that you're modifying the correct php.ini file? I know I've had a problem like that in the past, and it turned out I was modifying a php.ini file that wasn't even being used.

Comment: The phpinfo() shows which ini file is being used. Also the other settings that I changed upload_max_filesize & memory_limit worked fine, and I did a grep on the whole php5 directory and did not find a post_max_size in any other ini file.

Comment: PHP settings can also be set in a Apache virtual host configuration, or htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES!
Base on what Zoredache said I did a

```
:/etc/apache2$ rgrep post *
```

which found

```
sites-available/000-default.conf:       php_value post_max_size 128M
```

so a little

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo vi 000-default.conf
```

change php_value post_max_size 128M to 1024M and I am done!